# IPC-7351C polarization mark in real-life?

Tags: footprint

I know IPC-7351C is not released and probably won't be for... forever? The draft version of IPC-7351C differ from what's out there in the wild in many ways. For example, the draft uses a bar instead of a dot to indicate pin 1.

Has anyone seen any PCB with IPC-7351C land patterns in the wild (any photo, maybe)? Does the new silk screen cause any confusion at PCB assembly manufacturers?

Comment: In my (very limited) experience with PCBA houses, they ask for another file (not silk) with orientation whenever possible. (Super small packages usually dont have orientation marks anyway on silk).

Comment: KiCAD libraries typically follow this as well as the updated courtyard

Comment: @JonRB, thanks for the pointer. I found KiCAD has a Made-with-KiCAD page, which gives plenty of examples

Comment: IPC-7351B is the current standard, there is no such standard as IPC-7351C...

Answer (score 1):

One example is a card I recently design.

[image]

As you can see U1 follows this convention which is capture in  IPC-7351C

Likewise here is a render of a card I have in fabrication+assembly (2more weeks and you would see a picture and not a render)

[image]

As you can see, U2, U8, U7,U3 ... follow this convention.